# double conditions in IF statement in procedure

Tags: mysql

How can I use double conditions in IF in procedure MYSQL ?

```
IF (tbl = 'my_table' AND COUNTER < 1) THEN 
LEAVE table_loop; 
END IF;
```

is it possible ?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @mureinik I have only question - is it correctly piece of code ?

Comment: The code looks good. Have you tried it? Did it work?